# Drag & Drop between two listbox without add or Remove Button in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I have created one web page. In that i have used two listboxes. Now i want to drag an item from one listbox and drop the same item in another listbox. And also want to rearange the items without any help of buttons or any other controls.

can anyone help me in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to make this happen. Just use JQuery UI and implement the sortable function on the two containers. This will allow for drag&drop and sorting within the containers:

[JQuery Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)